# Leap Year Calculations using Method

Tags: java, class, methods, leap-year

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYearTester{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter a year");
      int year_input = input.nextInt();

      // now make a Year object

      Year theYear = new Year(year_input);

      // now check to see if it's a leap year

         if (theYear.isLeapYear())
         System.out.println("That's a leap year!");
         else
         System.out.println("That's not a leap year!");
   }
}


    public class Year
    {
    // declare your instance variables here
    private int theYear;
    private int Year;

    // write your constructor here
    public Year(int y)
    {
    y=Year;
    }
    static boolean isLeapYear(final int Year) {
    return Year % 4 == 0 && (Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 == 0);
    //(((Year%4==0) || (Year%400)) && ((!Year%100==0) || (Year%400=0)))  
    }

}
```

The above is the Main and cannot be changed. Having trouble with class.

Comment: " Having trouble with class." What trouble, with which class?

Comment: You have my sympathies.  Now what is your question?

Comment: Why do you have two `int` fields in your class? It also looks like your constructor isn't initializing either of them.

Comment: Why do newbies so often ask without reading the sites rules and requirements, all of which are easily found in the [help] section? Original poster, this question needs to be improved, including putting in effort to describe your code, your problem and to ask a *specific* question.

Comment: Hovercraft: why do we still wonder?

Comment: Don't name a variable the same as the class. Do follow the Java Naming Conventions.

Comment: Please note that "I'm having trouble with *x*" isn't really a question - see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: Your constructor does the exact opposite of what it's supposed to do

Answer (score 1):

Not much modification of your original attempt other than adding a check to see if the user entered a *valid year* in this case between 1000 and 2999 inclusive using regex (I will leave it as a task for you to modify this code for what you consider as a *valid year*):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class LeapYearTester {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a year: ");
    String yearInput = "";
    String pattern = "^[12][0-9]{3}$";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    //checking is valid year
    while(input.hasNext()){
      yearInput = input.nextLine();
      Matcher m = r.matcher(yearInput);
      if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("You entered the valid year: " + m.group(0));
        break;
      } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Not a valid year");
        System.out.print("Please enter a year between 1000 and 2999 inclusive: ");
      }
    }

    Year theYear = new Year(Integer.valueOf(yearInput));

    if(theYear.isLeapYear()) { 
      System.out.println("That's a leap year!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("That's not a leap year!");
    }
  }

  public static class Year {
    private int year;

    private Year(int y) {
      year = y;
    }

    private boolean isLeapYear() {
      if (year % 4 != 0) {
        return false;
      } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
      } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Example usage: Testing a leap year**

```
Please enter a year:  2016
You entered the valid year: 2016
That's a leap year!
```

**Example usage: Invalid input and testing a non leap year**

```
Please enter a year:  3000
Error: Not a valid year
Please enter a year between 1000 and 2999 inclusive:  2015
You entered the valid year: 2015
That's not a leap year!
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Fp42/1)

Comment: 1752 was *not* the first leap year.  The Gregorian calendar was in use as early as year 1582 in some parts of the world.  But besides that, the Julian calendar had leap years as well, going back to 45 BC.  Also, in computing we often use the *proleptic Gregorian* calendar system, which assumes we've always been Gregorian.  However you look at it, we've had them for a very long time.  (1752 is when Great Britain and the American Colonies adopted the Gregorian Calendar).  This is all on Wikipedia, BTW.